# how to upload image into server without using upload button in android

Tags: java, php, android

I want to upload image to server without using upload button, i am sending image path to next activity in that activity we have image preview..but my question how to upload that image into server without using click activity...that preview image should uploaded into server..Please help me..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

              setContentView(R.layout.cam);
   ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);



        image_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
        //Log.i(path, "image path in cam activity");
        view.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

        upLoadServerUri = "http://xxxhasdghs.com/apps/upload.php";


             uploadFile(image_path);
}
   public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 


          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               //dialog.dismiss(); 

               //Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"+image_path);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                      // messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"+ imagepath);
                       Toast.makeText(Cam.this, "Source File not exist :", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 


                       // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                               sourceFile);
                       URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                       // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                       conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                       conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                       conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                               "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);


                       // conn.setRequestProperty("image", fileName);

                       dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_img\";filename=\""
                                                 + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                       //Log.i("image value in php", mail);
                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 
                       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                       // read file and write it into form...
                       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  




                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                                //messageText.setText(msg);
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 Toast.makeText(Cam.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();


              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                         // messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                         // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          Toast.makeText(Cam.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          //messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          Toast.makeText(Cam.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss(); 

              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 


    }  

        }
```

logcat error

```
   03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at com.example.slimcell.CameraActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(CameraActivity.java:101)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at com.example.slimcell.CameraActivity$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(CameraActivity.java:1)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-12 12:59:23.703: E/AndroidRuntime(26390):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Comment: where is your `onCreate` method? Call your `uploadFile` method from `onCreate`.

Comment: How to create onCreate for uploadFile in my code..Can u please post the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to place your uploadfile method in [asynctask](http://curious-blog.blogspot.in/2013/06/pick-image-and-upload-to-server-in.html) and call that asynctask in oncreate method of activity. Call this asynctask in onCreate() in second activity. You have to download third party jar file to use multipartEntity from [here.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/nebn6a3cxpmj4k6/9781430226598.zip)

If ADT 17 jars need to be put into the libs folder or they wont be packaged with the apk. So either put them into libs or go to "configure Build Path.."->"Order and Export" and click the checkboxes next to your jars.

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
 private String webAddressToPost = "Your URL";

 // private ProgressDialog dialog;
 private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
  dialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
  dialog.show();
 }

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
  try {
   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(webAddressToPost);

   MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
   byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
   String file = Base64.encodeBytes(data);

   entity.addPart("uploaded", new StringBody(file));
   entity.addPart("someOtherStringToSend", new StringBody("your string here"));

   httpPost.setEntity(entity);
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

   String sResponse = reader.readLine();
   return sResponse;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // something went wrong. connection with the server error
  }
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  dialog.dismiss();
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

Comment: Check your webs ervices as well that it's working fine or not.

Comment: webservices are working fine...the result in response also shows null

Comment: When you check web service at that time response is null or not.

Comment: the web service not opened is browser. use Advance Rest api client to check web Service.

Comment: While logging the result it shows result<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN”> can anyone help me please

Comment: problem is in your webservice.